# Why is memory leaking in component tests (Jest with React Testing library)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

there are memory leaks in my component tests. I have React components and i use React Testing Library and jest for testing them.

I tried to debug them with this command to see heap usage.

```
node --inspect-brk --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage -c jest.unit.config.js
```

I sorted the results by shallow size and the biggest item from results is this *(string) x555392*
I see there MUI, React, Leaflet etc libraries multiple times with same shallow size.
[image]

Does this mean React etc is initialized multiple times in tests?

But i don't know why it would be initialized multiple times and how to fix it.

My tests looks like this:

```
describe('CustomIcon component test', () => {
    it('Renders element', () => {
        const WrappedComponent = baseHocUnitTests(CustomIcon);
        const { container } = render(<WrappedComponent propertyName={property.name} dataset={dataset} />);
        expect(container.querySelector('svg[aria-label="Primary key"]')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('Does not render element', () => {
        const WrappedComponent = baseHocUnitTests(CustomIcon);
        const { container } = render(<WrappedComponent propertyName={propertyWithoutIcon.name} dataset={dataset} />);
        expect(container.querySelector('svg')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

*baseHocUnitTests* is HOC with some providers:

```
export const baseHocUnitTests = <P extends {}>(WrappedComponent: FC<P>) => {
    const BaseComponent: FC<P & WithConditionalCSSProp<P>> = (props) => (
        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <EmoThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <WrappedComponent {...props} />
                </EmoThemeProvider>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </ReduxProvider>
    );

    return BaseComponent;
};
```

I tried to remove *baseHocUnitTests* wrapper in some tests where it is not necessary but it didn't help.

Thank you.

Comment: Just curious how are you importing. It is advised to use import  { useEffect,  useState } from 'react'; instead of import * from 'react';

Comment: like this `import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';`

Comment: Can you try moving baseHocUnitTests to beforeEach instead of calling each time

Comment: Thank you, I tried, no difference :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed that with jest `-w 2` parameter. I run unit tests with this command now and they are not failing anymore:

`jest -w 2 -c jest.unit.config.js`